# android how to create section spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

hello i want to create a sections spinner, i create this custom adapter making an adapter and having 2 different xml layouts, and i have an arrayList contains objects to bind. the object name is KamcoReportList , if it is header so i make IsSection value = true and i change the layout in adapter according to this value. but it doesnt work

```
   @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent){
 View v = convertView;
kamcoReportType report = values.get(position);
if (v == null) {
Context mContext = this.getContext();
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)       mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  if (report.isSection())

 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner_separator, null);
   else 
  v = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner_list_text, null);

  } 
    TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

   tv.setText(report.getName());

   return v;   
   } 


     @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   final kamcoReportType report = values.get(position);
   if (convertView == null) {
    Context mContext = this.getContext();
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   if (report.isSection())

   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner_separator, null);
   else 
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner_list_text, null);
   } 
   TextView tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

   tv.setText(report.getName());
  return convertView;

  }

  }
```